# Shiny: linking Shiny.outputBindings with output (issue with multiple outputs)

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a Shiny app that has 2 different, custom output controls. Each of these output controls has their own JavaScript bindings (`Shiny.OutputBinding()`) in separate .js files.

**How do I link a particular output binding to a particular output control?**

To demonstrate, I uploaded a [MWE as a gist](https://gist.github.com/stefanedwards/2b3cdf6cce66187e8d0004dac6c21ec9/f356d6d412fcfcb9cdd836dec7f976028887ce88), due to it being 3 separate files. To run, download the files and place the .js files in a `www` subdirectory.

The example is simple. There are two output controls, `redOutput` and `blueOutput`. Both outputs have their received value in a `<span>` element, with either blue or red color.

The files are linked as a singleton, to avoid including the script multiple times if the control is included multiple times.

**What happens:**

If only one of the controls is in the ui, it works as expected. The JavaScript bindings are linked in a `<script>` tag in the head, and we are happy.

If *both* controls are placed in the ui, *both* JavaScript files are linked in the head, and the latter takes precedence.

**How can I have *both* controls, each having their own `Shiny.outputBindings`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the bindings `find` function. Updating the gists to the following (for blue):

**app.R**

```
blueOutput <- function(inputId) {
  tagList(
      singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src="blue.js"))),
      div(id=inputId, class='blueOutput')
  )
}
```

**blue.js**

```
  find: function(scope) {
    // For the given scope, return the set of elements that belong to
    // this binding.
    return $(scope).find(".blueOutput");
  },
```

And yes, the solution was written plainly in the comment, I just did not connect the dots.

The [gist has been updated to reflect the solution](https://gist.github.com/stefanedwards/2b3cdf6cce66187e8d0004dac6c21ec9)